# How to detect the last row in CSV (ruby)

Tags: ruby, csv

```
data = IO::read(file).scrub("")
CSV.parse(data, {:col_sep => "\t", :headers => headers, :quote_char => '_'}) do |row|
  # how to detect last line of CSV?
end
```

I have a giant CSV file that needs to be scrubbed. It has multiple lines that apply to one DB object. In my code I'm collecting all the lines that apply to one object before passing them off to a class that will process them.

It would be very helpful if I could detect the last line in the CSV so I could make sure the last collection gets sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open(file_path) do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    row = CSV.parse_line(line.scrub(""), col_sep: "\t", headers: headers, quote_char: '_')
    file.eof?
  end
end
```

I went with this solution it does not require loading the entire CSV file prior to looping through which is helpful when dealing with large files.

By using File.open I can call file.eof? (end of file) which lets me know when I hit the last line.

Comment: Won't the inner block just run until it runs out of lines and thus you'll be at the end of the file when the that block ends?

Comment: correct. I was trying to trigger an action when it got to the last line and wanted to fire it within the each_line block.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a seek-based solution. This is optimized for larger files. No matter what the size of the file, it will take only a jiffy to print the last line of the CSV:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

f = File.open('test.csv')
f.seek(-2, IO::SEEK_END) #pos -1 is newline at end of file
last_line = nil

while f.pos > 0
  if f.getc == "\n"
    last_line = f.read
    break
  else
    f.pos -= 2  #getc advances position by 1
  end
end

row = CSV.parse_line(last_line.scrub(""), col_sep: "\t")
p row

f.close
```

Answer (score 2):

test.csv

```
first, second, third
1,2,3
3,4,5
7,8,9
```

test.rb

```
require 'csv'
headers    = 'headers'
filename   = './test.csv'
line_count = File.readlines(filename).size
file       = File.open(filename, 'r')
data       = IO::read(file).scrub("")
parse_opts = { col_sep: "\t", headers: headers, quote_char: '_'}

CSV.parse(data, parse_opts).to_enum.with_index(1).each do |row, line_num|
  puts line_num == line_count
end
#=> false
#=> false
#=> false
#=> true
```

The `line_count` is generated in ~8 sec on a 10+ million row CSV, you can alternatively use `line_count = %x(wc -l #{filename}).to_i` which takes ~1.7 sec on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

By parsing the data first you can check the length of the resulting array like this. To make this code runnable by itself without reaquireing an external csv file I put the data here at the end of the script in the __DATA__ part after __END__

```
require "csv"

csv = CSV.parse(DATA, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true)
csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts "#{row.fields} #{index+1 == csv.length ? '(last)' : ''}"
end
__END__
nr, Id, Name, URL
1, Google UK, http://google.co.uk
2, Yahoo UK, http://yahoo.co.uk
```

Which gives us

```
["1", " Google UK", " http://google.co.uk"] 
["2", " Yahoo UK", " http://yahoo.co.uk"] (last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
f = File.new("testfile")
dummy = f.readlines
f.eof   #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution but something like this perhaps?

```
data = IO::read(file).scrub("")
some_var = IO.readlines(some_file)

CSV.parse(data, {:col_sep => "\t", :headers => headers, :quote_char => '_'}) do |row|
  p row.join == some_var.last.chomp
end
```